# Ember.js - Get LinkView to re-render in handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem that I cannot create using fixtures in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OnuCaCep/38/edit).

The above code is really a wrapper around the link-to handlebars helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('resource-link-to', function(name, options) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var resource = this.get(name);
  var resourceRoute = resource.humanize();

  if (!options.fn) {
    options.types = ['STRING', 'STRING', 'ID'];
    options.contexts = [this, this, this];
    args.unshift(name);
    args.unshift(resourceRoute);
    args.unshift(resource.get('displayName'));
  } else {
    options.types = ['STRING', 'ID'];
    options.contexts = [this, this];
    args.unshift(name);
    args.unshift(resourceRoute);
  }

  var observer,
    _this = this;

  if (!resource.get('isLoaded')) {
    observer = function() {
      if (resource.get('isLoaded')) {
        //WHAT CAN I DO HERE TO GET THE LinkView to rerender?
        return resource.removeObserver('isLoaded', observer);
      }
    };
    resource.addObserver('isLoaded', observer);
  }

  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, args);
});
```

What I want to achieve is a generic link-to helper that takes any of my ember-data models and returns a link:

```
{{resource-link-to contact}}
{{resource-link-to user}}
```

etc.

This works great with fixtures but does not work with a real adapter because the model is not always loaded when the code forwards execution on to the real link-to helper or perhaps another way round this problem?

What I wanted to do was create an observer that re-renders the LinkView when the resource is loaded like this:

```
  var observer,
    _this = this;

  if (!resource.get('isLoaded')) {
    observer = function() {
      if (resource.get('isLoaded')) {
        //WHAT CAN I DO HERE TO GET THE LinkView to rerender?
        return resource.removeObserver('isLoaded', observer);
      }
    };
    resource.addObserver('isLoaded', observer);
  }
```

Anybody any idea how I can get the LinkView to re-render?

Comment: This is a fun idea, I don't see any template areas that would be rendered before an async model was returned.

Comment: Another way might be to have a subclass of LinkView that does something.  I need to get a better understanding of how LinnkView works.

Comment: link view is a bound helper, have you tried just using Em.set on the args object and see if the link updates?

Comment: I've tried that and notifyPropertyChanged also  No cigar.

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about the solution I came up with [here](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2014/01/24/custom-link-to-refactor/).